# I got this message when submitting App

Tags: xcode5

Note: iAd does not use the AdSupport framework, ASIdentifierManager, or the Advertising Identifier. Therefore they are not required for iAd implementations and should not be included in your app for iAd support.

Please check your code - including any third-party libraries - to remove any instances of:

class: ASIdentifierManager
selector: advertisingIdentifier
framework: AdSupport.framework

While I do have AdSupport.framework, I have removed it. I also cannot find ASIdentifierManager anywhere. How the hell it get into my archive?

I am supposed to use this tool called nm but I am confused on how to use it.

I did

Jupiter:BadgerNew Teguh$ grep -r advertisingIdentifier .

```
Binary file ./Crashlytics.framework/Versions/A/Crashlytics matches
```

So crashlytics is the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hemal from Crashlytics here. With the Crashlytics Mac app open, compile your app and upgrade the SDK to 2.1.6 which will take care of this for ya! For more info, check out this [link](http://support.crashlytics.com/knowledgebase/articles/316358-how-is-the-advertising-identifier-used-) :)

Comment: I got a message saying unable to install sdk. Please contact support support@crashlytics.com

Comment: Hey Jim, restart the Mac app and give it another go!